# How to remove single or double quotes for the items in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I should remove the single or double quotes for the items in the list.
My list is

```
lis=['greaterthan','lessthan']
res='[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str,lis))
print(res) #[greaterthan,lessthan]
print(type(res)) #<class 'str'>
```

I need list type even after removing the quotes.I tried many ways I am able to remove quotes but its showing in string format,but I need list type.
can anyone suggest.

Comment: "I need list type even after removing the quotes" there *are no quotes in the string in your list*

Comment: ['greaterthan,lessthan'] these are the quotes

Comment: **There are no quotes in that string**. Check yourself, `lis = ['greaterthan,lessthan'] ; print("'" in lis[0])`. Of course, when you *write a string literal* you use quotes, and when a `str.__repr__` will add quotes, and when you print that list, the `__repr__` of the objects inside is what's used, **but there are no quotes in that string** so it is completely unclear what you are trying to accopmlish.

Answer (score 1):

We can do something like this:

```
lis[0].split(',')
```

This will give you a list with the words separated by a comma:

```
['greaterthan', 'lessthan']
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want quotes for those items in the list.I just need [greaterthan,lessthan] #<class 'list'> is that possible

Comment: Hi @Swarnitha, thank you for your feedback! It is not possible unfortunately because those items are strings. i.e., type('greaterthan') == str

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
lis=['greaterthan,lessthan']
res = lis[0].split(",")
print(res) #['greaterthan', 'lessthan']
print(type(res)) #<class 'list'>
```

Comment: thanks but  i don't want quotes for those items in the list.I just need [greaterthan,lessthan] #<class 'list'> is that possible

Comment: @Swarnitha **that doesn't make any sense**. There **are no quotes in those strings**. `[greaterthan, lessthan]` is an expression, it is a list literal with two objects inside referenced by variables, but that is *source code*

Answer (score -1):

To address the part: 'I just need [greaterthan,lessthan] #<class 'list'>'

If you 'remove' quotes around string you get a name (reference to an object). Therefore you can do:

```
greaterthan = object()
lessthan = object()
lst = [greaterthan, lessthan]
```

Comment: actually I wrote a flask api, from that api user gives  greaterthan,lessthan in the parameter I will get them to a list using request.args.getlist(key)  so from that I will get ['greaterthan,lessthan']  i need to remove those quotes and get [greaterthan,lessthan] in list type.

Comment: List type - check, no quotes - check. You got exactly what you ased for. If it is not satisfactory for you, then maybe you should ask the 'right question'. Otherwise you will always get 42 as Amazingly Accurate Answer to Life, the Universe and Everything